# Can Armadillo be used on clusters?

Tags: cluster-computing, armadillo

From the Armadillo install instructions:

> If you are using sparse matrices, also install ARPACK and SuperLU.
>   Caveat: only SuperLU version 4.3 can be used!

On the [SuperLU site](http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/) there are three versions available: SuperLU, SuperLU_MT and SuperLU_DIST. Since the requirement is version 4.3, does it mean that only the single threaded version can be linked to Armadillo? If so, it means, that for sparse matrices only single PCs can be used, I cannot make use of the cluster available at my university.